# Toolbar gives fatal error on menu inflate in Intent/AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, menuitem, android-include

In my app I have a toolbar which is working perfectly fine in my MainActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_item_counter"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_tv_itemCounter"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I try to inflate this menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/item_accept"
    android:title="Accept"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

With this code

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_input_accept);

    TextView toolbartext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_tv_itemCounter);
    toolbartext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
```

}

It gives me this

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.inflateMenu(int)' on a null object reference

fatal error which I don't understand. I also tried to overwrite the onCreateOptionsMenu method and use the MenuInflater there like I do in my MainActivity but it changes nothing. I included my toolbar in the xml like I did in my main activity:

`<include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/include" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I included my toolbar in the xml like I did in my main activity:
>
> ```
>    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
>     android:id="@+id/include" />
> ```

When you include a layout, if you provide an id to the include tag(like you did, by using *android:id="@+id/include"*) then the root of the included layout will have that id, overriding any id already assigned inside the included layout. So in your case the Toolbar has an id of *R.id.include* and not  R.id.toolbar.

Either remove *android:id="@+id/include"*, change it to *android:id="@+id/toolbar"* or look for the Toolbar using *findViewById(R.id.include)*.

Comment: I saw it myself like 1sec ago but thank you anyways xd That facepalm I was so mad ^^